# C#, SSH. How to read the contents of a file, send it via ssh for processing and return it back?

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

How by C# to read the contents of a file, send it via ssh for processing and return it back? Is it possible with library SSH.NET?

I have a signature server. I execute a command on my computer and get a signature file
Command (cmd):

```
type file.txt | ssh sign@signserver sign.sh > file.txt.signed
```

(Read the content, send the content via ssh for signing and return the signature file)

How can I do the same in C#? Can you suggest an example please?
How to do stdin, stdout?

Thank you in advance

```
type file.txt | ssh sign@signserver sign.sh > file.txt.signed
```